# How to add action to automatic back button in TableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `ViewController` which is embedded and second `TableViewController`. The segue identifier between this two controllers is "abc". And now when I click the button in `ViewController` I go to `UITableViewController`. Back button in TableViewController shows me automatically. And now:

How can I add action to this Back button? I need is because I need to send some data from `TableViewController` to `ViewController`

Comment: Add navigation and pass push segue.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi can you give me an example?

Comment: you can use custom delegate methods, call your delegate method from viewWillDisappear.... for more about delegate methods have a look at this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-custom-delegates--mobile-10848

Comment: ok but it is in Objectiv-C not SWIFT, and I don't now Objectiv - C

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have embedded the navigation controller and make sure it is the initial view controller .

open your table view controller in the storyboard and where the back option is present drag a button at that place . Connect the button into the file of the tableView controller as an 'action' and write your code.